# Hidden console window, but allow popup window?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

A coworker wrote a PowerShell script that makes repetitive AD tasks *much* easier.  However (I don't know the details), he wrote it in such as way that you have to open `powershell.exe` and hit "Run" to execute the script.  We already have a million windows open on our machines, and having one more is simply too many.

So, I'm trying to write a .vbs that runs a hidden console, but allows the .ps1 file to open up a window. Currently, it just flashes for a split second and disappears.

Code:

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 0
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
objProcess.Create "powershell.exe -command myscript.ps1", null, objConfig, intProcessID
```

If I set `HIDDEN_WINDOW` to 0, it hides EVERYTHING.  Is there a way to hide the initial console, but show the window created by the .ps1?

Comment: I think you need to reboot.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The process is either hidden or not. It can't be partly hidden.

Comment: I eventually figured it out. Basically, I could use powershell to launch itself the way I want. I went an additional step and use the script to pull the username and insert it into the path.

`Dim strUser
Dim usrPath
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
usrPath = """\\somePath\" & strUser & "\myscript.ps1"""`

And here is the part that launches PS hidden, but allows it's script to be seen:

`strCommand = "powershell -WindowStyle hidden -command " & usrPath`

The & usrPath concatenates the path. You could just type the path in and skip all the variable junk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, as commented above. The variable `usrPath` refers to a variable that I use to store that path and the `&` concatenates it to the following PowerShell command:

```
strCommand = "powershell -WindowStyle hidden -command " & usrPath
```

This accomplishes what I wanted, as PowerShell allows to have a hidden console, where VBS and Windows Scripting do not.